# Gerar números primos e inteiros de grande proporção

Tags: php, criptografia

Como eu faria para gerar números Primos de 300 dígitos por exemplo em PHP? E números inteiros da mesma proporção? Preciso deles para uso em criptografia com [Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).

Comment: É mais fácil pegar uma lista de números prontos em vez de ficar calculando.

Comment: http://www.floatingdoghead.net/bigprimes.html

Comment: @bfavaretto em hipotese alguma! Nao é pra experimento, ´é pra uso na prática.

Comment: Em hipótese alguma por que? O link que eu passei é para justamente para uso com o algoritmo que você quer. Os primos que você usa no algoritmo não precisam ser secretos.

Comment: Gerar primos em PHP ou é falta de conhecimento, ou de ferramentas, ou ambos. Pegue uma base de dados pronta, e de lá você seleciona os que quiser, seja aleatoriamente, seja com parâmetros determinados. E não existe número primo secreto, se eu calcular uma tabela de primos aqui em casa vão ser os mesmos primos que qualquer outra pessoa calcular.

Answer (score 3):

Eu concordo com o bfavaretto que o mais fácil é montar um *array* com todos os números. Os softwares reais fazem isto. Só vale à pena criar na mão se for exercício para aprender mas aí você deveria fazer. Como não parece ser o caso eu sugiro esta solução preponderantemente. [Lista da Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prime_numbers).

Se puder usar um biblioteca como a [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-nextprime.php) pode fazer assim:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 300; ++$i) {
    echo $i = gmp_strval(gmp_nextprime($i + 1)) . "\n";
}
```

Se quiser um algoritmo pode usar este que pode ser melhor otimizado:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 300; $i++) {
    $cont = 0; 
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) {
        if($i % $j == 0) $cont++;
    }
    if ($cont == 2) print $i . "\n";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/D55Cmh). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xkzhdbsj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Math/Gmp.php).

Comment: O segundo método não vai chegar nos 300 dígitos, certo? Repare que o requisito não era `<= 300`, e sim que tivessem 300 dígitos.

Comment: Nem o primeiro :) Embora seja possível, agora que eu vi que ele quer 300 dígitos :) Vou ver o que dá para fazer. Qdo eu tiver tempo p/ ver eu restauro.